# How parse JSON string when I have a child node that sometimes comes as an object and some times as an Array?

Tags: java, android, json

I am creating a very simple Android app which use Retrofit to retrive a JSON string. I found, after look the string in detail something strange. This is the JSON String:

```
{
"promotions":[
    {
    "button":{
        "target":"https://m.abercrombie.com",
        "title":"Shop Now"
        },
        "description":"GET READY FOR SUMMER DAYS",
        "footer":"In stores & online. Exclusions apply. <a href=\"https://www.abercrombie.com/anf/media/legalText/viewDetailsText20150618_Shorts25_US.html\" class=\"legal promo-details\">See details</a>",
        "image":"http://anf.scene7.com/is/image/anf/anf-US-20150629-app-women-shorts",
        "title":"Shorts Starting at $25"
        },
        {
    "button":[
        {
        "target":"https://m.hollisterco.com",
        "title":"Shop Now"
        }
        ],
        "description":"Our Favorite Brands",
        "image":"http://anf.scene7.com/is/image/anf/anf-US-20150629-app-women-brands",
        "title":"Dolce Vita"
        }
        ]
}
```

If you look carefully, the two "button" nodes are different, the first one is take like an object and the second is an Array of the same object. This is my POJO.

public class Promotion {

```
@SerializedName("button")
@Expose
private Button button = new Button();
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("footer")
@Expose
private String footer;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
```

With this, the first "button" node take it right but the second one shows and error that tells me is specting an Array not an object. If I change my Button declaration as follows:

```
private List<Button> button = new ArrayList<>();
```

the second one gets right but the first one says is specting and object and not an Array.

My question in, how can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you have two keys with the same name `button`? and different value types? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: Where is the JSON being created? Are you controlling the that? There is no need, at least in the example, for the second button to be an array rather than an object.

Comment: Yes I know but I do not have control of the API, the JSON string comes that way and I can not change it.